# Primary key value error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> Attaching an entity of type 'app.Models.LookupMatchStatus' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate
>   I reviewed a few posts regarding this issue, but don't know if the accepted answers apply to my issue or not.

Our users are getting intermittent errors when using an application we built.
Since I cannot recreate the issue, can anyone tell me if replacing the following would fix the issue:

```
var vMatchStatus = context.LookupMatchStatus.Single(x => x.Code == "UMTC");
```

with

```
var vMatchStatus = context.LookupMatchStatus.**AsNoTracking()**
                                .Single(x => x.Code == "UMTC");
```

---

```
public ActionResult UpdateUnmatchedRecord(long? SelectedId)
{
    if (Session["user"] != null)
    {
        if (SelectedId == null)
        {
            if (TempData["Data"] != null)
            {
                long globalID = GetSequence();
                using (HCPInsightsEntities context = new HCPInsightsEntities())
                {
                    ListMatchDetails unResolvedRecord = (ListMatchDetails)TempData["Data"];
                    if (!TempData.Keys.Contains("ListMatchId"))
                    {
                        TempData.Add("ListMatchId", unResolvedRecord.ListMatchId);
                    }
                    var vMatchStatus = context.LookupMatchStatus.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.Code == "UMTC");
                    //Original Below
                    //var vMatchStatus = context.LookupMatchStatus.Single(x => x.Code == "UMTC");
                    unResolvedRecord.LkupMatchStatusId = vMatchStatus.LkupMatchStatusId;
                    unResolvedRecord.RowSelected = null;
                    unResolvedRecord.GlobalId = globalID;

                    if (TryValidateModel(unResolvedRecord))
                    {
                        context.ListMatchDetails.Attach(unResolvedRecord);
                        var entry = context.Entry(unResolvedRecord);
                        entry.Property(x => x.LkupMatchStatusId).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(x => x.RowSelected).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(x => x.GlobalId).IsModified = true;
                        context.SaveChanges();
                        UpdateListMatchJob(unResolvedRecord.ListMatchId, false);
                        Session["reconcile"] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Reconcile");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "Login");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I get it all from above details. If items in `TempData` are shared and in a multi-user scenario, someone else is already saving the item before (the user who gets the error). Another thing is that if `globalID` is the primary key, chances are it gets repeated.

Comment: Temp data shouldn't be an issue as two or more users can never be working with the same record and 'globalId' is established with a SQL Sequence. Makes sense why you would ask though. Sorry for the lack of details.

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone tell me if replacing the following would fix the issue:

*Maybe*.

Lets first start off by *why* the problem exists.  First [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) is an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) that by default, cache's the model it creates from retrieving data from a database in an internal cache contain inside a [DbContext](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/dbcontext.aspx).  It does this to attempt to reduce the number of calls to the database, and allow local changes in the context without affecting the database so it can optimize nd correctly order sql events on a `SaveChanges()`.

In your example code, it retrieves a `LookupMatchStatus` via:

```
var vMatchStatus = context.LookupMatchStatus.Single(x => x.Code == "UMTC");
```

This places the item in the local cache.  Then the code attempts to place another item with the same key of the same type in the cache via:

```
context.ListMatchDetails.Attach(unResolvedRecord);
```

This is just an assumption since you haven't given any stacktraces nor a specific line that throws the exception it's very hard to determine how the error is occuring, why and how to fix it.

So will simply using `AsNoTracking()` fix the problem... well *maybe*.  The method is designed to prevent model's from being inserted into the cache.  I don't know if that specific line is the problem or something else..

Comment: Sorry for not including the stack trace. It didn't include a line number but it referenced the  LookUpMatchStatus object which is why i assumed it was in the line I referenced. I can include the entire trace if you want to take a look if the first line below isn't enough:
Stack Trace
[InvalidOperationException: Attaching an entity of type 'app.Models.LookupMatchStatus' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Comment: FULL ERROR:`Attaching an entity of type 'app.Models.LookupMatchStatus' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary
key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in
the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.`

Comment: Don't comment Question information.  Instead edit your original question to include relevant information.  This helps future users understand the question better and if they are having the same problem without having to read all comments.